# LiveData: Dialog via DialogFragment gets recreated twice after orientation change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-orientation, android-livedata

I have a liveData object that I use to control when my alert dialog is shown or not. 
this alert dialog is based on a DialogFragment. 
The alert is shown when the `onChanged(true)` is called for this liveData.

Now when the alert is showing and the orientation changes,  the alert is re-created twice, one on top of the other. 
This seems to be because, Android by default re-creates the alert when the orientation changes but then the liveData `onChanged(true)` is again called when the orientation changes. So the alert is created twice.

Is there a way to stop Android from re-creating the dialog itself so that I can handle the recreation once myself via the LiveData object?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this solution https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

Comment: post some code to see

Comment: y the down vote?

Comment: how did u handle the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a dialog, you can make the dialog object null every time it get closed, and while popping it out create a new object. And every time check for null case, if it is not null do no open another dialog. If null then only open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check, with 'if ()' statment if

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
```

or

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById("idOfDialog")
```

return null, if yes there is no dialog, and you can create new. 
Other solution i to use, Handle Configuration Changes. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes
With this, you can place your observer of liveData in onCreate, and it won't trigger while rotation, only when liveData change, but this is more complex to do.

Answer (score 0):

this is because when config changes happened, android itself creates one more layer on top of it.
hope this will help.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // only create fragment if activity is started for the first time
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
} else {        
    // do nothing - fragment is recreated automatically
}
```